# How to setup session sharing for language subdomains (URL language detection set to domain prefix)

Tags: i18n-l10n, sessions

I would like to use domain prefix for language selection, like en.example.com and de.example.com. I've set up language detection to `Domain` here `admin/config/regional/language/configure/url`.

In theory everything works fine, except that session data is not shared between subdomains. If I log into the main site example.com and then visit en.example.com I have to log in again. Is this behaviour by design? Can I setup drupal to share session data between subdomains? It's the same site after all - only subdomain is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the variable `$cookie_domain` in your `settings.php` file to your base (default language) domain.

Just search the settings.php file for that variable, uncomment the line and replace '.example.com' with your default language domain preceded with a dot.

[Source](http://drupal.org/node/1545778#comment-5913206)